# ¿Como actualizar datos en sql mediante c#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net

Disculpen tengo una aplicación en ASP.NET donde tengo almacenado varios usuarios, al momento que estos se entran en su cuenta, pueden modificar los datos del perfil excepto nombre de usuario y correo, pero al momento de dar clic en el botón de actualizar este recarga la página pero no ejecuta la sentencia sql.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        cn.ConnectionString = ruta;
            SqlCommand cmd = cn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = CommandType.Text.ToString();
        using (cn)
        {
            cn.Open();
            cmd.CommandText = string.Format(@"UPDATE Registro_de_usuarios SET" + "[nombre] = @nombre, [apellidos] = @apellidos,  [contraseña] = @contraseña" + " where [nombre_usuario] = @nombre_usuario", cn);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombre", TextBox1.Text);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@apellidos", TextBox2.Text);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombre_usuario", TextBox3.Text);


            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contraseña", TextBox5.Text);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

    }
```

El dato de usuario y correo aparece por defecto y no se pueden modificar, y tomara en cuenta el nombre de usuario para hacer el cambio

Comment: Te recomiendo (y a todos) que dejen de utilizar `AddWithValue` ya que puede generar problemas al momento de enviar datos a la BD. https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Answer (score 1):

Aconsejaria ordenes un poco el codigo aplicando correctament el `using` y como definir el string de la operacion de update, algo como ser:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ruta))
    {
        cn.Open();

        string update = @"UPDATE Registro_de_usuarios 
                            SET [nombre] = @nombre, 
                                [apellidos] = @apellidos,  
                                [contraseña] = @contraseña 
                            where [nombre_usuario] = @nombre_usuario";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(update, cn);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombre", TextBox1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@apellidos", TextBox2.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contraseña", TextBox5.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombre_usuario", TextBox3.Text);

        int rowAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        LblResult.Text = string.Format("Se actualizaron {0} registros", rowAffected);

    }
}
```

Si defines un label, para ver en un mensaje la cantidad de registros que fueron actualizados.

Sino observas ninguno es a causa del `where` que recibe un valor para el cual no hay ninguna coincidencia